# Unity Compute Shader Texture Array Sampling

Tags: unity-game-engine, buffer, textures, hlsl, compute-shader

I've been struggling with this for while now and it is quite time critical so I have to ask here. I'm quite new to compute shaders but from what I've read, it is what I need for my usecase. I'm trying to find the total score from an array of textures, with the score being the product of each channel and a given weight. Previously, I was using NodeJS to do it but it doesn't scale as well given increasing the dimensions by 4 would increase the area required per texture by 16 and with multiple textures this isn't a good solution.

This is my compute shader right now:

```
// Each #kernel tells which function to compile; you can have many kernels
#pragma kernel CSMain

// Create a RenderTexture with enableRandomWrite flag and set it
// with cs.SetTexture
SamplerState linearClampSampler;
float4 weights;
RWStructuredBuffer<Texture2DArray<float4>> scoreInput;
float output;

[numthreads(8,8,1)]
void CSMain (uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
float4 result_mult = scoreInput[id.z].Sample(id.uv).rgba * weights.xyzw;
output = result_mult.r + result_mult.g + result_mult.b + result_mult.a;

}
```

For my C# dispatcher, I am doing:

```
string[] paths = new string[sessionData.masks.Length];
Texture2D[] textures = new Texture2D[sessionData.masks.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < sessionData.masks.Length; i++)
{
paths[i] = sessionData.masks[i].combinedMasks;
textures[i] = CustomUtility.LoadPNG(paths[i]);
}
int colourSize = sizeof(float) * 4;
ComputeBuffer wallBuffer = new ComputeBuffer(textures.Length, colourSize);
wallBuffer.SetData(textures);
CalculateScoreShader.SetBuffer(0, "scoreInput", wallBuffer);
CalculateScoreShader.Dispatch(0, 8,8,1);
```

I can't figure out how to sample the texture properly, and I want to make sure that I am setting up the buffer correctly for the shader to used like this. I also want to retrieve the output, but again I'm unsure how to do this.

I have looked through a decent amount of tutorials and documentation but I just can't seem to find the solution.